# Permissions in wordpress plugin with URL parameters

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to develop a plugin for wordpress.
Everything works fine, but when I pass parameters by URL says:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_options_add_pages');


function theme_options_add_pages() {
    add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 1, __FILE__, 'main_page');
}



function main_page() { ?>

<div id="theme-options-container">
    <form>
    <div id="theme-options-header">
        <img id="theme-options-logo" src="../wp-content/plugins/theme-options/images/wordpress-logo-hoz-rgb.png" alt="Your logo here"/>
    </div>
    <div id="theme-options-clear">
        <div id="theme-options-sidebar">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <ul role="navigation">
                <li id="theme-option-general">
                    <a href="#"><div class="theme-option-image"></div>General Settings</a>
                </li>
                <li id="theme-option-styles">
                    <a href="#"><div class="theme-option-image"></div>Styling Options</a>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="theme-options-content"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<?php }
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a capability and a slug:

`add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'my-theme-options', 'main_page' );`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page